# How to convert a kernel smoothed probability density estimate into units of 'stuff'

Tags: matlab, 3d, probability, probability-density

I am currently working with multivariate probability distributions (MATLAB function [`mvksdensity`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvksdensity.html)) but I have one problem holding me up.

I have a 3D PDF of [XYZ] points in space. I would like this to be in units of points, like an estimated count of points per bin, instead of probability.

This is because I would like to have an estimate of the number of points found in certain regions, I would like to convert the PDF to time (by multiplying by 1/sampling rate) and I would like to divide different PDFs of different data etc.

My first thought is to divide the PDF by its sum (so sum(PDF) = 1) then multiply by the total number of [XYZ] points. This way the sum(PDF) = the count of points and I should be able to do all of the above.

Basically my question is how to convert a PDF into something more like a histogram – so that the units are 'stuff' rather than probability...

Any help would be massively appreciated,

Thanks,

Rod.

Here is a toy example of what I mean:

```
pos = rand(50000,3)*1000; % [XYZ] points
vindx = 0:50:1000; % grid over which we want to estimate KDE
[xv,yv,zv] = ndgrid(vindx); % grid over which we want to estimate KDE
f = mvksdensity(pos,[xv(:),yv(:),zv(:)],'Bandwidth',75,'Kernel','normal','Function','pdf'); % PDF
f = f./nansum(f(:)) .* length(pos(:,1)); % now the sum of f will = the number of [XYZ] points

map = NaN(length(vindx),length(vindx),length(vindx)); % prepare an empty 3D map
[~,idx] = ismember(xv(:),vindx); % get the indices along X
[~,idy] = ismember(yv(:),vindx); % get the indices along Y
[~,idz] = ismember(zv(:),vindx); % get the indices along Z
ida = sub2ind(size(map),idy,idx,idz); % get the indices into map
map(ida) = f(:); % add the values to map

figure % plot data
isosurface(map,nanmax(f(:))/2);
daspect([1 1 1])
```

Comment: Your PDF should sum to 1. Multiplying by the number of points would lead to a number in each “bin”.

Comment: @CrisLuengo that's what the example in the question seems to be doing. The more relevant question I think is in what respect is the example not a solution to the question?!

Comment: Also note that a KDE from samples taken from a finite-support uniform distribution (`rand`) will be approximately uniform over the support (`0:1000` in this case) but also non-zero beyond the support limits because of the width of the kernel. If you only evaluate the KDE at points in the range of the input data the result will integrate to less than `1` because KDE posits that for every observed data point there's a probability of seeing a new point some distance beyond it.

Comment: Hi guys, in Matlab the output of functions ksdensity and mvksdensity do not sum to one. The integral of the output sums to 1. You can see that in the example, for me nansum(f(:)) = 7.14-06 or thereabouts. So the question is if what I have done is an appropriate way to proceed - if so, that's great! But I'm not sure...

Comment: If your aim is for `f` to represent how many points in `pos` fall into each `50`-unit cube then this is *almost* appropriate. Because your grid doesn't go below `0` or above `1000`, integrating `mvksdensity` over that grid should give you less than `1`. Dividing by `nansum(f(:))` will hence overestimate how many points would fall in each grid cell according to the KDE, because it assumes no points fall outside the grid whereas the KDE assumes some do.

Comment: The output of `mvksdensity` has the units `(input units)^-1`. So you can estimate the proportion of all points that fall in a 50-unit grid cell by multiplying by `50^3`. This essentially implements the assumptions of a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum).

Comment: So, as a general rule you mean multiplying by the grid interval (i.e. 50 in my example) cubed will give an approximation of the local density/proportion of data per bin? What about the bandwidth of the KDE, won't that effect things? Also, just to clear up the grid problem; in my example the data range between 0 and 1000 and the bin edges do as well. But in reality my real grid of points is padded out from the data edges to avoid this.

Comment: Using the example code above, if I try [ f = f .* (50^3); ] the sum of f is not 1 (although it is close at around 0.9)

Comment: The difference between the sum of your computed values and `1` is entirely a result of how good an approximation that sum is as a numerical integral of the whole PDF. A good approximation needs a grid that extends far enough to capture the volume under the distribution tails, and have a small enough step size to capture the shape of the PDF. Changing the bandwidth will only affect how close the integral is to 1 inasfar as it changes how far the grid needs to extend and how fine it needs to be to capture the shape of the distribution.

Comment: Will - can  you summarise what you have said as an answer so I can accept it? I have tried what you suggested and it works perfectly, so it is definitely the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability density function represented by `mvksdensity` already has units of "fraction of the total population per unit volume of *XYZ*". Multiplying by the original number of points will indeed convert this to "number of points from the original sample per unit volume of *XYZ*".

These units are essentially the same as those for a histogram where the bins have *unit volume*. If one element output is to represent a larger bin, multiply by the volume of the bin to represent the number of points expected to fall within that number of unit bins.

Evaluating `mvksdensity` over a grid of points will leave a grid of values which are a numerical approximation of the PDF defined by kernel density estimation. Multiplying this by the grid cell volume (which for your grid `ndgrid(vindx)` equals `50^3`) produces values which form a [numerical approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) of the integral of the PDF when summed.

The *analytical integral* of the PDF over the whole *XYZ* domain is *defined* to be `1`. For your values to fairly reflect the PDF defined by KDE, you shouldn't divide through by the sum as you do in your example with `f./nansum(f(:))`. If the numerical integral `nansum(f(:) * 50^3)` doesn't equal `1`, this reflects the approximation error of the numerical integral, and either indicates that the grid doesn't extend far enough or is too coarse.

Comment: This basically answers my problem, so I have accepted it here. I'm not sure how general it is though. For instance I am now using mvksdensity to approximate probability over the surface of a sphere. How does this answer apply there because the bins no longer have a constant volume/area?

Comment: `mvksdensity` assumes distances between points are Euclidean, so if your input points are spherical coordinates the density estimate will be wrong to start with. A point just next to the north pole of your sphere will make the same density contribution at a point just on the other side of the pole as a point on the equator will make at a point diametrically opposite it. So long as the assumptions made by `mvksdensity` hold, it should remain trivial to sample from the distribution at uniform intervals.

Comment: I don't understand that; my points are XYZ coordinates but they fall on a unit sphere. I calculate the probability density estimate at a bunch of points on this sphere (matlab function 'sphere'). I agree that the precision of the estimate will be greater at the poles because there are more grid points there, but the actual value should not be incorrect. I don't understand your example either: a point near the pole will contribute to a point just on the other side of the pole, but it will make a far weaker contribution to a point on the opposite pole (diametrically opposite).

Comment: With 3D cartesian points on a sphere you have a different problem: the points are defined and assumed to be distributed in 3 orthogonal dimensions. This means `mvksdensity` models nonzero probability density at points inside and outside of your sphere as well as on its surface, even though there is actually none.

Comment: You could derive the transformation that would allow you to determine the "equivalent volume" of each face of the UV-sphere returned by `sphere` to allow you to integrate the values, but this is quite a convoluted band-aid for the underlying problem which is that you're using an inappropriate model for the probability density of your data. I expect it would be easier to implement KDE from first principles using a non-Euclidean distance metric than to figure this out; in any case, it's beyond the scope of this question which addresses uniform cartesian grids in a Euclidean space.

Comment: Yes, I think I see the problem. There is actually a spherical implementation of KDE based on the von Mises-Fisher distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution) so I have moved to that, with some minor modifications. It doesn't really change the result all that much. This solves the spherical grid problem but then I'm back to square one in terms of normalising the output to reflect real values... I think I will just avoid using these KDEs for actual data analysis and instead use them for visualisation.